# How to test a function (node module) if it's called with chai-spies / Mocha / Test

Tags: node.js, express, mocking, mocha.js, chai

I want to test if a function is being called with chai-spies.

This is the class I want to test

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

router.post('/login',(req,res) => {

    const {username, password} = req.body;
    let login= {};
    login.username= username;
    login.password= password;
    try{

        request.post({    // <---- this is the function I want to test if its called
            header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json', 'accept ': 'application/json'},
            url: ' https://exmple',
            json: login
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            // implementation
        });
        } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
});
module.exports = router;
```

and below is my test file i tried to write

**index.test.js**

```
const route = require ("../routes/index");
const spy = chai.spy.on(route,'request');
const request = require("supertest");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const chai = require('chai');
let spies = require('chai-spies');
chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

//create app without credentials
let app = express();
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(route);

describe("Testing the POST /login route", () => {

let spy = chai.spy.on(route,'request'); // I tried to mock the function here with chai spies.

 it('should make a request to backend server when form is filled, but with wrong credentials', (done) => 
 {
        request(app)
            .post('/login')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .send({username:"test",password:"test"})
            .end(function (err,res) {   
                expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once;
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

As you can see i tried to mock the request function with chai spies
*let spy = chai.spy.on(route,'request');*

but when I run the code it does recognize the mocking function and return

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Spy 'object.request' } to have been called once but got 0
    + expected - actual

    -0
    +1
```

How can I test the request function if it is called. The request is actually a node module to make a http call on another backend server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mock the `request.post` method correctly. Besides, you should implement the controller of the `/login` route, which means you need to send some data to the client use `res.send()`, `res.json()` or `res.end()`. Otherwise, the supertest client will not get a response, it will make the test case timeout.

Here is an example:

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  let login = {};
  login.username = username;
  login.password = password;

  try {
    request.post(
      {
        header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json', 'accept ': 'application/json' },
        url: ' https://exmple',
        json: login,
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        res.send('implementation');
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const route = require('./');
const request = require('request');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const chai = require('chai');
let spies = require('chai-spies');
chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

//create app without credentials
let app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(route);

describe('Testing the POST /login route', () => {
  let spy = chai.spy.on(request, 'post', (options, callback) => {
    callback();
  });

  it('should make a request to backend server when form is filled, but with wrong credentials', (done) => {
    supertest(app)
      .post('/login')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .send({ username: 'test', password: 'test' })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once;
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  Testing the POST /login route
    ✓ should make a request to backend server when form is filled, but with wrong credentials (47ms)


  1 passing (63ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   92.31 |      100 |     100 |   92.31 |                   
 index.js |   92.31 |      100 |     100 |   92.31 | 23                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```